# twenty seventeen theme: comments UI not visible

Tags: comments, user-interface

I'm new to WP, so I may be missing something. But I've tried everything and cannot figure out how to display the comments UI on posts. When I switch to different themes, the problem is resolved and I can see the comments box. But no luck whatsoever in the twenty seventeen theme. Any advice? I've spent a good amount of time trying to set up my new blog on this theme and I'd like to use it. But there seems to be some type of glitch. Thanks.

Comment: did you do any update to the theme ? did check well the comment options ?

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem and wasted SO many hours, until I read someone else's post explaining that in most themes the comment UI only shows up on the INDIVIDUAL blog post page, ie, the page that loads when you click on the title of the post, NOT on the landing page for the blog posts. Don't like it, but don't think it can be changed...